# T1 Fontenc only changes text body font - not Koma Headlines

Tags: koma-script, font-encodings

[image]this is probably an easy and stupid question, but I can't find out how I get fontenc to change the font of my headlines. For the text Body it works.

```
% Font settings
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% Koma Settings (also headlines)
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, fontenc changes the encoding not the font. Better make a small but complete example and show what you think is wrong.

Comment: Your example is incomplete and so it is hard to understand your question. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` has almost no visible effect, it changes the internal font encoding used from 7-bit OT1 to 8-bit T1 but as there is no hyphenation in page heads I would not expect any visible change to the page head. Please fix your example so that it is a complete small document that shows the problem, and say what output you expected.

Comment: Sorry im quite new to Latex so its hard to explain - also Im not sure if there is something wrong, but definitely not the output I would like to achieve. Ive added a picture, which shows that the headlines and text body are in a different font, which I would like to be the same (both Helvetic). Ive added the two parts of my document config, as these are the only ones which could influence the font type. My question is, how I can manipulate the font settings of the headlines to also be Helvetic. I already looked for the Koma and fontenc instructions, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: your picture shows you are asking about section headings, which but your code and original question appeared to be about page headings and both are unrelated to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as requested above please post an example. As it stands your question is far to unclear to even guess an answer.

Comment: Try with `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\sffamily}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It worked with \addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ulrike Fischer. It could be achieved with

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
```

[image: The picture shows the output]